# ASP.NET Core: why using IOptions adapter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a custom options block (`MyOptions`) in the `appsettings.json` configuration file like this:

```json
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "test": "..."
    },
    "MyOptions": {
        "Prop1": "Value1",
        "Prop2": "Value2"
    }
}
```

My POCO looks like this:

```cs
public class MyOptions
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

In `Startup`, I register it as shown below:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   var configSection = Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions");
   services.Configure<MyOptions>(configSection);
}
```

My controller requests it by using the adapter 'IOptions':

```
public IndexController(IOptions<MyOptions> options)
{
    // ...
}
```

Here is my question: why must I use the adapter `IOptions`? The official documentation says that `IOptions` is a singleton. Is there some benefit using `IOptions` instead register the `Options` as a service like this?

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   var configSection = Configuration.GetSection("MyOptions");
   var option = configSection.Get<MyOptions>();
   services.AddSingleton(option);
}

public IndexController(MyOptions options) // <- Request it without the IOptions adapter
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: There's quite a bit of overlap between in the two. In the back the `Configure<T>()` even calls a the `AddSingleton` method. The main difference is that using the options pattern has some additional features such as validation, named options, etc... and is more conform to standards. Also; currently your code will read the options the first time they are called, while with the singleton you read them at startup but the same could also be achieved with singleton.

Comment: This [section from simpleinjector documentation](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/servicecollectionintegration.html?highlight=IOptions#working-with-ioptions-t) has some interesting options about what you are referring to